# Jenkins cannot access git

Tags: git, jenkins

After a crash of the Jenkins server, I cannot start my projects builds.

I get this weird message. Any clues?

```
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master --prune" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: error: object file .git/objects/10/f103eb6e4590be766e67ca961e65f5c4e6836c is empty
error: object file .git/objects/10/f103eb6e4590be766e67ca961e65f5c4e6836c is empty
fatal: loose object 10f103eb6e4590be766e67ca961e65f5c4e6836c (stored in .git/objects/10/f103eb6e4590be766e67ca961e65f5c4e6836c) is corrupt
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same a few times.

Sometimes the answer of @"Mukesh M" may help - that is a decent approach. In other cases, the following approach helped me a few times.

First visit the /var/jenkins_home/caches folder. Delete the git-hashes. The next start of the job will retrieve everything from git again so the job will run smooth again. So omitting the git cache.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I did following

Select Workspace and click on Wipe Out Current Workspace. This will delete your workspace.

Now just start new build and it will work.

[image: Jenkins Wipe Out Current Workspace]